# HackerRank's Nested List Problem:-Facing issues with 2 out of 10 test cases

Tags: python, nested-lists

The following is my attempt at the solution.The result needs to be ordered in lexicographical order which i did but i am not getting why the test cases which i mentioned below after the #Code aren't working.

#Code

```
N=int(input("enter number of students in the range of 2 to 5"))
physics_students=[]

#creating a list of student names with their grades
for i in range(N):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    physics_students.append([name,score])
physics_students.sort()

#Removing the lowest grade
grades_list=[]
for i in range(N):
    grades_list.append(physics_students[i][1])
grades_list.sort()
grades_list.remove(min(grades_list))

#finding out the names of students with second lowest grade
for i in range(N):
    if physics_students[i][1]==grades_list[0]:
        print("name",physics_students[i][0])
```

## Test Cases which didn't pass are as follows:

Test Case 1:
4
abhay
-50
sri
-50
rakesh
-50
kishore
51

Test Case 2:
5
ram
20
ramesh
20
suresh
19
venkat
19
jaydeep
21

[Hacker Rank's problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem)

Comment: You should probably ask this in the discussion for the task. See https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/forum

Answer (score 1):

The blunder's here:

```
grades_list=[]
for i in range(N):
    grades_list.append(physics_students[i][1])
grades_list.sort()
grades_list.remove(min(grades_list))
```

> HackerRank Problem Descriptor
>   Note: If there are **multiple students** with **the same grade**, order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.
>   <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

Now consider if there were multiple students with the same *lowest* grade. Let's say the grades were `[1, 1, 2, 3]`. This becomes your sorted `grades_list`.

Now what happens when you call `.remove()`?

```
>>> grades_list.remove(min(grades_list))
>>> print(grades_list)
[1, 2, 3]
```

So you see, that the `min` isn't fully removed.

There are several ways to solve this, but I want to leave the implementation to you since this is a pretty good exercise.

Spoiler:

> Hint: Maybe try keeping only *distinct* elements in your `grades_list`?

---

#### Other Issues

```
N=int(input("enter number of students in the range of 2 to 5"))
```

There shouldn't need to be a prompt there. It'll spoil the standard output and HackerRank will mark it as wrong.

```
print("name",physics_students[i][0])
```

This also. You can remove `name`. : )

Answer (score 0):

here is the short code for problem.

```
score_list = [];
if __name__ == '__main__':
   for _ in range(int(input())):
       name = input()
       score = float(input())
    
    
       score_list.append([name, score])
second_highest = sorted(set([score for name, score in score_list]))[1]
print('\n'.join(sorted([name for name, score in score_list if score == 
second_highest])))
```

Comment: This question is over three years old and already has two answers. Do you see how the accepted answer explains what the problem is? That is much more helpful than dumping code without any explanation. Please read [answer].